# error: incompatible types Simple game selection with scanner?

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is, I have 2 games, one called ToF, and one called spin.
If entered string was "spin", start the spin game. and turn console input into int.

If entered int was 1, spin the wheel.
If entered int was -1, change console input to String, and get out of the loop.

But I am getting this error:

```
src\Main.java:39: error: incompatible types
input = console.nextLine();
```

My properties:

```
    private static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Spin spin = new Spin();
    private static String input = "";
    private static String[] gamesArray = new String[] {"spin", "tof"};
    private static boolean spinWheel = false;
    private static boolean tof = false;
```

And there is the error:

```
        while (input.equals("spin")) {
            System.out.println("Spin game!");
            spinWheel = true;
            int input = console.nextInt();

            if (spinWheel) {
                System.out.println("Welcome to the spin game! Please write 1 to spin. and -1 to exit back");

                switch (input) {
                    case -1:
                        input = console.nextLine();
                    break;

                    case 1:
                    break;
                }                   
            }
        }
```

***What is wrong? Why is it doing this? How can I fix this?***

Comment: `Scanner#nextLine()` returns a String. And you are assigning it to an `int`. You should use `Scanner#hasNextInt()` in combination with `Scanner#nextInt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
this.input = console.nextLine();
```

because you are hiding `input` with your local `int` variable with the same name.

A cleaner solution would be giving one of the two variables a different name.